# I have a remotely published website program that I want to debug locally. I should do it

Tags: c#

I have a remotely published website program that I want to debug locally. I should do this. Is there a good solution? The development tool is vs2015.

Comment: google "visual studio remote debugging"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio have remote debugging feature. You have to attach remote address process (server iis) but firt you have to deploy your code with debug symbols (*.pdb files).